# Plot a Heat Map onto Sphere - Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap, colormap

I have a set of cartesian coordinates `(x_sph, y_sph, z_sph)` sitting on the surface of a sphere. `x_sph`, `y_sph`, `z_sph` are each 1D arrays, so the first coordinate on on the sphere is `(x_sph[0], y_sph[0], z_sph[0])`, for example.

Each of these has a scalar value associated with it, `intensity_sph`, which is also a 1D array.

**I want to plot these intensity values as a heatmap on the surface of the sphere**, but so far I'm struggling - matplotlib requires the z to be a function of x and y, which is not the case here.

So far I have the rather hacky solution of plotting a scatter plot of the sphere points, with a colour associated with the intensity of that point, which kind of gets the point across but not as well as I'd hoped:

[My 'hacky' solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lzrH.png)

Does Matplotlib's 'Basemap' package help? Thanks for any help!!

The code is as follows (the `fibonacci_sphere()` function generates the sphere points):

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import os
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.colors as colors

def fibonacci_sphere(num = 1, radius = 1):
    """
    Returns the coordinates of 'num' points evenly distributed on a sphere.
    """
    rnd = 1.

    x_vals = []
    y_vals = []
    z_vals = []

    offset = 2./num
    increment = np.pi * (3. - np.sqrt(5.));

    for i in range(num):
        y = ((i * offset) - 1) + (offset / 2);
        r = np.sqrt(1 - pow(y,2))

        phi = ((i + rnd) % num) * increment

        x = np.cos(phi) * r
        z = np.sin(phi) * r

        x_vals.append(x)
        y_vals.append(y)
        z_vals.append(z)

    x_vals = [(radius * i) for i in x_vals]
    y_vals = [(radius * i) for i in y_vals]
    z_vals = [(radius * i) for i in z_vals]

    return np.array(x_vals), np.array(y_vals), np.array(z_vals)

##################
## CREATE DATA  ##  
##################
# Specify number of points on the sphere
num_points = 10000

# Create coordinates sitting on the surface of the sphere
x_sph, y_sph, z_sph = fibonacci_sphere(num = num_points)

# Create random data for the 'intensity' at each point on the sphere
intensity_sph = np.random.rand(num_points)


#########################################
## MAPPING INTENSITY VALUES TO COLOURS ##
#########################################
minima = min(intensity_sph)
maxima = max(intensity_sph)

norm = colors.Normalize(vmin = minima, vmax = maxima, clip=True) # what's clip?
mapper = cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=cm.jet)


############################
## CREATE FIGURE AND PLOT ##
############################
# Create figure and axes
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection = '3d', xlabel = 'x (m)', ylabel = 'y (m)', zlabel = 'z (m)')

# Plot scatter plot 
ax.scatter(x_sph, y_sph, z_sph, c = intensity_sph, cmap = cm.jet)

plt.show()
```